# String interpolation for array using map in scala

Tags: scala

I have an array = `("1","2","3")`

and I also have a string that I want to format: `"item = {} found"`

I want to get an array: `("item = 1 found", "item = 2 found", "item = 3 found")`

Comment: Something like `Array("1", "2", "3").map(x => s"item = $x found")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for a more generalized solution.

```
def formatter(ss :Array[String], format :String) :Array[String] = {
  val braces = "\\{}".r
  ss.map(braces.replaceFirstIn(format, _))
}

formatter(Array("1", "2", "3"), "item = {} found")
//res0: Array[String] = Array(item = 1 found, item = 2 found, item = 3 found)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `map`:

```
val array = Array("1", "2", "3")
array.map("item = " + _)  // Array("item = 1", "item = 2", "item = 3")
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work in my case. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
val array = Array("1", "2", "3")
array.map(i => s"item = $i found")
```